# Site.com studio: using styles in content blocks

Tags: site.com, stylesheets

I can see how I can create text styles in Site.com studio by editing a style sheet.  I can see how I can use a style as an ID or a Class by specifying the properties of an entity.  But I can't work out how to, when editing a Content Block, highlight a section of the block and apply a class/ID style to it.  The only options seems to be selecting a paragraph type (Paragraph, Heading 1, Heading 2, etc.), or manually setting the text formatting.  Am I missing something?  I can't believe this is the case, as it would be a real issue if a site was being created with multiple different styles.